# Getting this Error: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' during npm run build

Tags: c#, .net, npm, .net-core, npm-run

I am getting this Error:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' in assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' is not marked as serializable
during npm run build.
I generate a dll file in my 1 project and copy it into 2 project. After running npm run build, it gives me above error.[image]

Comment: Does this project use remoting? It seems `AutoMapper` (which I don't recommend to anyone because it causes [more problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/247359/199250) than it solves) threw an exception remotely but as its `AutoMapperConfigurationException` is not `[Serializable]` it couldn't be transferred to the local side so you got another exception that tells that the original exception is lost. Maybe doesn't help too much but I recommend not using `AutoMappter` but some direct mapping, which is much cleaner and maybe the issue comes out immediately at compile time, too.

Comment: no, it is not using remoting.
Sorry but that's not in my hand. It is client choice.

Comment: Anyhow, something wants the exception to be serializable, which is a sign that it is tried to be serialized by a `BinaryFormatter`, `SoapFormatter` or another `IFormatter`. If you have access to the serializer initialization you can try to use a serialization surrogate that is able to serialize any type (like [this one](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector.htm)). Or, if you can catch the exception before being serialized rethrow it as a serializable one (eg. `InvalidOperationException`) with the original message.